# JQuery AJAX response never being reached

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, stripe-payments

Im developing a simple Bootstrap website for a charity, which accepts credit card donations & those are processed by Stripe.

While all the Stripe processing works fine (i log onto the system & can see the payment), it seems the JQuery AJAX response is never being reached (i.e: in debugger, i place a line break on the AJAX response - but its never reached).

So I'm quite sure my issue is with the JQuery AJAX call, but im not sure where.  Or otherwise there's an issue with the PHP returning its JSON data.

The HTML form:

```
<form class="contact-form" id="payment-form" onsubmit="return onSubmitDo()">
              <div id="creditcard">
                <span class="payment-errors"></span>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback row">
                  <label for="card-number" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">Card Number: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="tel" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm card-number cc-number" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••" data-stripe="number" required>
                  </div>
                  <label for="card-cvc" class="col-sm-1 form-control-sm">CVC: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="tel" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm card-cvc cc-cvc" placeholder="•••" data-stripe="card-cvc" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback row">
                  <label for "card-expiry" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">Card Expiry: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="tel" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm card-expiry cc-exp" placeholder="•• / ••" data-stripe="exp" required>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cardExpMonth" data-stripe="exp_month">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cardExpYear" data-stripe="exp_year">
                  </div>
                  <label for="cardname" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">Name on Card: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" size="20" autocomplete="off" name="cardname" id="cardname" data-stripe="name" required>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="separator-2"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken" value="">

                <h5>Select Donation Amount</h5>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputAmount" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label form-control-sm ">Your Donation Amount: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-12">
                      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="10"> $10
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="50"> $50
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="100"> $100
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="200"> $200
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio5">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio5" value="500"> $500
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio6" value="other"> Other
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-4 form-control-sm">
                          <input type="tel" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="inputAmount" id="inputAmount" placeholder="">
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <div class="separator-2"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <h5>Your Contact Information</h5>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">First Name: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="first-name" id="first-name" autocomplete="off" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">Last Name: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="last-name" id="last-name" autocomplete="off" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">Email: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">Address: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <textarea name="address" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="address" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="city" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">City: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="city" id="city" autocomplete="off" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">Phone: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="phone" id="phone" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="state" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">State: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <select name="state" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
                        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                        <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
                        <option value="SA">SA</option>
                        <option value="WA">WA</option>
                        <option value="NT">NT</option>
                        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <label for="zip" class="col-sm-2 form-control-sm">Post Code: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="zip" id="zip" maxlength="4" required pattern="[0-9]{4}" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert" style="display:none" id="waitMess"> Please wait while we process your donation... </div>
                  <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" style="display:none" id="compMess"> Thankyou for your donation, we greatly appreciate it. </div>
                  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none" id="errMess"> </div>
                  <div class="form-row form-submit">
                      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default submit-button">Submit Donation</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Javascript for creating Stripe Token:

```
<script>
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_************************');

    function onSubmitDo () {
      document.getElementById("waitMess").style.display="block";
      document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
      Stripe.card.createToken (document.getElementById('payment-form'), myStripeResponseHandler)
      return false;
    };

    function myStripeResponseHandler (status, response) {
      console.log(status);
      console.log(response);

      if (response.error) {
        document.getElementById('payment-error').innerHTML = response.error.message;
        alert (response.error.message);
      } else {
        var tokenInput = document.createElement("input");
        tokenInput.type = "hidden";
        tokenInput.name = "stripeToken";
        tokenInput.value = response.id;
        //alert(response.id);
        var paymentForm = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        paymentForm.appendChild(tokenInput);
        document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = response.id;
        submitPHP();
        //paymentForm.submit();

      }
    };
    </script>
```

JQuery AJAX:

```
function submitPHP() {
  var form = $('#payment-form');
  var formData = $(form).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/donate.php",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    if (data.paid == "yes") {
      $("#waitMess").css("display", "none");
      $("#errMess").css("display", "none");
      $("#compMess").css("display", "block");

    } else {
      $("#waitMess").css("display", "none");
      $("#compMess").css("display", "none");
      $("#errMess").css("display", "block");

    }
  }
})
};
```

The PHP which submits Stripe payment (API keys are contained within config.php):

```
<?php

  require_once 'config.php';
  require_once 'stripe/init.php';

  //Receive the data posted
  var_dump($_POST);

  try {
    $token   = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $email   = $_POST["email"];
    $firstname = $_POST["first-name"];
    $lastname = $_POST["last-name"];
    $name    = $firstname." ".$lastname;
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $city = $_POST["city"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $state = $_POST["state"];
    $postcode = $_POST["zip"];

    // get the value of either the radio button or input box
    if (empty($_POST["inputAmount"])) {
      $amount = $_POST["inlineRadioOptions"];
    } else {
      $amount = $_POST["inputAmount"];
    }

    // create a customer if our current user doesn't have one
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            'source' => $_POST['stripeToken'],
            'email' => strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']))
        )
    );

    $customer_id = $customer->id;

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
         'customer' => $customer->id,
         'amount' => $amount * 100,  //sends amount in cents
         'currency' => 'aud',
         'description' => 'General Donation',
         'metadata' => array("Name" => $name, "Address" => $address,"City" => $city, "State" => $state, "PostCode" => $postcode, "Email" => $email, "Phone" => $phone)
    ));
    $stringMess = "Thankyou for your donation of ".$amount." ".$name." , we greatly appreciate it.";
    $result = array("paid"=>"yes","text"=>$stringMess);
  } catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
    $result = array("paid"=>"no","text"=>$e);
  } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
    $result = array("paid"=>"no","text"=>$e);
  } catch (\Stripe\Error\Api $e) {
    $result = array("paid"=>"no","text"=>$e);
  } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    $result = array("paid"=>"no","text"=>$e);
  }

  echo json_encode($result);
  ?>
```

Comment: are you saying that the `$.ajax` `success` method is never called? have you tried putting in an `error` method to see if that's being called instead?

Comment: yes always use a error callback for all jQuery AJAX call, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR) }

Comment: if i change the AJAX to test it, so the code has this:
`success: function (data) {
     alert('success');
     if (data.paid == "yes") {`
the alert is never fired.

As to using an Error callback/method - not sure on how to implement it (as im relatively new to AJAX with JQuery)

Comment: are you seeing the request in the Network tab of the developer tools (press F12)

Comment: I added an error Callback, i found it was producing this error:
"JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

I also check the network tab, and found this is what's being returned;
`{"paid":"yes","text":"Thankyou for your donation of 500 John Doe , we greatly appreciate it."}`

So it appears the PHP is returning a JSON object, but Jquery is having issues parsing it.

Comment: If i change my ajax call to instead have:
`dataType: "text"` then i don't get the json parse error from ajax;

But if i do this, while the debugger in my browser states that its a JSON object, jquery wont interrupt it as JSON, as it sees a string like `"{\"paid\":\"yes\",\"text\":\"Thankyou for your donation of $500 test test , we greatly appreciate it.\"}"` and i think the "\" is then throwing off jquery,

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things in debugging the code i originally posted, i ended up back at my original code - which then suddenly worked.

So it looks like i had a **'white space bug'** somewhere in the code.